# Run-Time Error 1004 When Pulling in PowerPivot Created Measures

Tags: excel, vba

I am a new member and I couldn't find any specific resolution to the issue I'm experiencing. I am getting Run-Time Error 1004:

> Application Defined or object-defined error

when trying to add cubefield values. Error on: `.Orientation = xlDataField`
It sometimes work but I mostly get this error and trying to find a permanent fix for it. I am using Excel 2016 version.

Here's the VBA Code I am using:

```
Sub UnhideALL()  

Sheets("Availability_Details").Select

 With TROCUserForm
  .Top = Int(((Application.Height / 2) + Application.Top) - (.Height / 2))
    .Left = Int(((Application.Width / 2) + Application.Left) - (.Width / 2))
    .Show False
    End With
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Range("M17").Select

     With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of Booked]")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 2
    End With

      With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of Build]")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 3
    End With

      With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").CubeFields("[Measures].[Available_Y_N]")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 4
    End With

         With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").CubeFields("[Measures].[Tech_Net_to_85]")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 5
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").CubeFields("[Measures].[Tech_Net_to_75]")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 6
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").CubeFields("[Measures].[Tech_Net_to_65]")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 7
    End With

    Range("G9").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").PivotFields("[Measures].[Sum of Booked]") _
        .Caption = "Bkd"

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").PivotFields("[Measures].[Sum of Build]"). _
        Caption = "Blt"

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("QuotaAvail").PivotFields("[Measures].[Available_Y_N]") _
        .Caption = "Avail"
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    Range("G9").Select

    Call TechNet85Cond
    Call TechNet75Cond3
    Call TechNet65Cond3
    Call Wholenumber

    Unload TROCUserForm

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the problem will be resolved if you use the .AddDataField method to add the measures to the Values area. Fire up the macro recorder and add a field manually, then inspect the code produced to get the syntax. For my sample data, it looks like this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Measures].[ Value]"), " Value"
```

I imagine you will have to check first to see whether the measures are already in the PivotTable, or perhaps throw a blanket ON ERROR RESUME NEXT in there to handle that situation.

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").CubeFields("[Measures].[ Value]"), " Value"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Looks like its the original fields, Booked and Build that's causing the issue. I created a measure the sums booked (named: Sum_of_Booked) and build instead and just used that measure instead of the original fields.